# Removing elongated, "thin" parts of shapes using R

Tags: r, polygon, geometry, slivers

I have a dataset with a lot of polygons, of which some are long and thin in shape (see image). I'd like to remove their "extremities".

Is there a tool/method to remove thin parts of a polygon in R?*

In the example, the elongated shapes vary in shape and thickness

- I thought about using a shape-ratio (e.g. perimeter/area, as described *[here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222345/identify-shape-of-the-polygons-elongation-roundness-etc)*), but that only allows me to remove complete polygons, whereas in some cases I'd like to preserve the "roundish" part of a polygon.
- I'd like to be able to experiment with thresholds to find a suitable setting for the "roundness".
- [Removing thin rectangles from a shapely polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/280488) seems like a similar problem, but I'd rather not use shapely

[image: example of polygons with elongated shapes]

Comment: One approach would be to apply a buffer with a negative size (i.e. shrink polygons), then apply a buffer with the same but positive size. You'll also lose details of the 'wide' parts of the polygons however.

Comment: When you talk about "complete" and "parts" of a polygon, are you talking about individual polygons of a multipolygon feature? Because you can totally split multipolygons into polygons, filter on area/perimeter and rebuild multipolygons in R with the sf package...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear there. With "parts" I was *not* referring to "polygons of a multipolygon" but "a portion of a continous polygon", e.g. the two elongated "arms/antlers" of the red polygon in the middle/bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using buffer

1. Buffer with a negative distance, for example -50
2. Buffer with +60
3. Clip the buffers with your original polygons

Answer (score 4):

Buffering with negative distance and then the positive distance (plus some extra to account for loss of detail) as suggested in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/414929/34517) can be realized with this code (in R):

```
BUFFER_WIDTH = 10
    
# negative buffer removes parts of the polygons
poly = raster::buffer(poly, width= - BUFFER_WIDTH )
    
# positive buffer recreates shape from the remainders
poly = raster::buffer(poly, width=   BUFFER_WIDTH + (BUFFER_WIDTH * 0.1))
```

Comments:

- this will also work like a **smoothing** operation
- intersecting the buffers with your original polygons is only needed if you want the original (more detailed) outline
- you may want to filter small areas (red), that might be created by artifact leftovers after negative buffering. In R: `poly_new <- drop_crumbs(poly, threshold = AREA_THRESH)`

**Result**: Blue original polygon, green/red resulting polygon.
[image: Blue original polygon, green/red resulting polygon after removing elongated parts.]